# Replication in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication, radius, transactional-replication

I want to do transactional replication on MySql. There is no built in wizard like the one for SQL Server 2008 so I finding it a little tricky.

I read that you could use FreeRadius to set replication up but there instructions on how to do this.

OK, I have set this up but I have an issue. Sometimes this set up fails due to lost internet connection etc and the replication stops and data is no longer replicated to slave.  The problem is that there is no way of telling if the replication has stopped or not. I have to manually check it which is very frustrating. Is there a way of checking if this set up fails?

Answer (score 1):

This is called **statement-based replication** (often abbreviated as SBR), which corresponds to the standard statement-based binary logging format. In MySQL 5.1.4 and earlier, binary logging and replication used this format exclusively.

source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-formats.html

**EDIT 1:**

if connection breaks you can set `slave_net_timeout` variable to reconnect

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_slave-net-timeout

**EDIT 2:**

check this article

http://www.danielschneller.com/2006/10/mysql-replication-timeout-trap.html

Comment: ok, i have set this up but i have an issue. sometimes this set up fails due to lost internet connection etc and i the replication stops. problem is that there is no way of telling if the replication has stopped or not. I have to manually check it which is very frustrating. Is there a way of checking if this set up fails?